# Parse Excel Cell at special character

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a cell like so , "7.35+.094", is there anyway I can parse this cell with a formula to get "7.35". I dont want to use text to columns, I want to do it within one formula.

My current cell A1 = `=Sheet2!A56` which is "7.35+.094",  How can I alter this formula to get "7.35"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, use:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("+",A1)-1) & CHAR(34)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gary, I meant to give `7.35` without quotes, sorry about that.

Comment: @Jonathan If there are no double-quotes in **A1**, then use:  ***=LEFT(A1,FIND("+",A1)-1)***

Comment: thank you Gary, one last question, what if I wanted to find + or -

Comment: @Jonathan, if you know there would only ever be one +, and that if it is not found there there will be a - instead you could wrap the current formula in an IFERROR function and then for the error result repeat the formula but replace the + with a -

Comment: @ForwardEd Can you show me what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

To build on Gary's Answer to the original question.  If there is a + OR a - there take Gary's formula,  place it in an IFERROR function and then repeat the formula using a - as the error part of IFERROR as follows:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND("+",A1)-1) & CHAR(34),LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1) & CHAR(34))
```